# OWIN fails to start with "The network location cannot be reached"

Tags: c#, console-application, owin

I'm trying to run the following code on a .NET 4.5 Console app:

```
var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://127.0.0.1:9000/");
```

This works on my colleagues machines but not mine.

The exception message reads "`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`" with an inner exception of "`The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help`".

I have tried turning off my firewall, resetting my hosts file, no anti viruses are running, flushed my DNS and cleaned/rebuilt my solution.

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.StartServer(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)
   at OwinTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\OwinTest\OwinTest\Program.cs:line 12
```

If I change the code to this it works:

```
var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9000/");
```

But the above code is not what I'm looking for.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a whole day of research and troubleshooting, the following command worked:

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

When I ran this in command prompt, I did not receive any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://0.0.0.0:9000/");
```

0.0.0.0 should mean it's listening on all IPs...

Comment: This works: `http://[::1]:9000/` and this works `http://localhost:9000/`

Comment: Well... `::1` is IPv6 addressing. Looks like IPv4 is not enabled whatsoever